# How to install the Class::Method::Modifiers module in Perl?

Tags: perl, dependencies

I'm trying to use the library MSGConvert to convert outlook emails to .eml emails, but I have had some dependency issues with perl (I think).
The backtrace indicates that I may need to install a perl module. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

```
Cant locate Class/Method/Modifiers.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Class::Method::Modifiers module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Moo/_Utils.pm line 43.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Module/Runtime.pm line 317.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Module/Runtime.pm line 317.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Email/Sender/Role/CommonSending.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Email/Sender/Role/CommonSending.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Module/Runtime.pm line 317.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Module/Runtime.pm line 317.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/bin/msgconvert line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/msgconvert line 9.
Unexpected Error!
```

Comment: Usually, one installs [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib), then `cpan Class::Method::Modifiers`. But `cpan Email::Outlook::Message` should handle all the dependencies for you.

Comment: I already did `cpan -i Email::Outlook::Message` but the issue persists

Comment: How is your cpan configured? Does is install prerequisites?

Comment: Also, what does line 9 in /usr/local/bin/msgconvert say? Is it [this](https://metacpan.org/source/MVZ/Email-Outlook-Message-0.918/script/msgconvert#L9)?

Comment: how can I see how is my cpan configured?
and Yes line 9 is that.

Comment: Run `cpan`, then in the cpan shell type `o conf prerequisites_policy`.

Comment: `nolock_cpan[6]> o conf prerequisites_policy`

    `prerequisites_policy [follow]`
`Type 'o conf' to view all configuration items`

Comment: Can you post the whole log of `Email::Outlook::Message`?

Comment: `$ cpan -i Email::Outlook::Message`
`Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages`
`Reading '/home/laptop1/.cpan/Metadata'`
  `Database was generated on Fri, 14 Jul 2017 15:54:03 GMT`
`Email::Outlook::Message is up to date (0.918).`

Comment: I mean the whole log of the original installation.

Comment: I could fix the dependency error installing "Moose" with
`sudo perl -MCPAN -e"install Moose"`
Thank you so much!